# React with react-redux-firebase isLoaded is true and isEmpty is seemingly false, yet firebase.auth().currentUser is null - what could be the cause?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom, react-redux-firebase

so I might have difficulty explaining this issue I am having, which I am not able to reproduce consistently. I have a React app on which I am using `react-redux-firebase` and that I thought I was successfully implementing to keep track of the user session.

My App.js file has the following bit or routing code as a sample (using `react-router-dom`):

```
<Route
    path="/signin"
    render={() => {
        if (!isLoaded(this.props.auth)) {
            return null;
        } else if (!isEmpty(this.props.auth)) {
            return <Redirect to="/posts" />;
        }
        return <Signin />;
    }}
/>
```

This works correctly. I go to `Signin` component when user is not logged in or `Posts` when user is logged in. In `Signin` component I have this bit of logic that  happens:

```
        // sign the user in
        this.props.firebase.login({
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        }).then(response => {

            // detect the user's geolocation on login and save
            if (isLoaded(this.props.auth)) {
                const navigator = new Navigator();
                navigator.setGeoLocation(this.props.firebase);
            }

            // redirect user to home or somewhere
            this.props.history.push('posts');
            
        })
```

I am importing isLoaded like so:

```
import { firebaseConnect, isLoaded } from 'react-redux-firebase';
```

the condtional works fine, the user is logged in and then the `isLoaded` conditional happens - this is where the problem arises. With isLoaded true I would assume that the user and all the redux-firestore user properties are ready for use....but that is sometimes not the case. In navigator.setGeoLocation call I have this:

```
setGeoLocation(propsFirebase, cb) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            propsFirebase.auth().currentUser
                .getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
                .then((idToken) => {
                    ...
                });
            }
        )
    }
}
```

At this point, propsFirebase.auth().currentUser is sometimes null (this originates in the parameter passed in `navigator.setGeoLocation(this.props.firebase);`). If I try the signin in all over again, then it works. I am not able to find any consistent way of reproducing.

I have noticed this in other components too. I am not sure if this is an issue that happens when my computer goes to sleep and I should restart the whole React process or what? has anyone seen similar issues? If so, what could I possibly be missing during checking user state in the routing?

If more code is necessary, let me know...

Comment: Is it randomly that it is not the case? Or does it happen always?

Comment: Seems random...it happens once, then doesn't happen again at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[currentUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser) will be null with the user is not signed in.  It will also be null when a page first loads, before the user's token has been loaded and a User object is available.  You should use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to get the User object if you want to act immediately after it is loaded asynchronously after page load.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

You might also want to read for more detail: [Why is my currentUser == null in Firebase Auth?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0)

Comment: This is great, seems like this is what is happening to me - question: if (user) - is user the same object as firebase.auth().currentUser ? Can I assume that if user is set, then firebase.auth().currentUser  also will be?

Comment: If you get a callback from the observer function, you can be sure that currentUser will be non-null just after the callback completes.  Inside the callback, you should use the provided user object.